# Pokemon battle simulator

Tags: python, pygame, battle-simulation, pokemon

I learned Python and Pygame and now have coded a few games. For the last few months I have been working on this "luck free" pokemon battle simulator. I feel my program runs well in the current state and at the same time is being semi spaghetti-coded because as I try to improve the game I find it more challenging than it should.

I know there are some things done wrong or improperly. Any constructive criticism you have to input is appreciated. There are multiple more files you can find [here](https://github.com/fudgenuggets1/hax_free_pokemon).

Here's the **game.py** file where the majority of the battle code is:

```
from __future__ import division
import pygame, Functions, math, time, computer_move
from yo_buttons import Button
from pokemon import *
from vision import *
from pokemon_types import *


class Game():

    home_screen = Home_Screen()
    team_builder_screen = Team_Builder_Screen()
    play_screen = Play_Screen()
    options_screen = Options_Screen()
    gym_leaders_screen = Gym_Leaders_Screen()

    screens = []
    screens.append(home_screen)
    screens.append(team_builder_screen)
    screens.append(play_screen)
    screens.append(options_screen)
    screens.append(gym_leaders_screen)
    current_screen_number = 0

    Pokemon_Team = test_team
    Pokemon_List = Pokemon_Team.list
    opponent = test_opponent
    Opponent_Pokemon_List = opponent.list

    current_pokemon_number = 0
    current_opponent_number = 0

    current_turn_text = set([])
    turn_text = set([])
    battle_text = []
    current_turn = 0
    turn_index = -1
    dead_text = ""

    current_turn_sprites = [Pokemon_List[0], Opponent_Pokemon_List[0]]
    turn_sprites = set([])
    battle_sprites = []
    current_sprites = [Pokemon_List[0], Opponent_Pokemon_List[0]]
    battle_sprites.append(current_sprites)

    pause = False
    previous_screen = None
    square_info = ["","","",""]
    show_party = False
    Pokemon_Party = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    Opponent_Party = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    Pokemon_Fainted = False
    switched_in = False
    switching = False
    opponent_switching = False
    second_move_info = None
    first_move_done = False
    second_move_done = False
    going_to_switch = False
    text_y = 75
    can_switch = True
    opponent_can_switch = True
    next_move_text = pygame.image.load('images/next_move.png')
    next_pokemon_text = pygame.image.load('images/next_pokemon.png')
    exit_text = pygame.image.load('images/exit_text.png')
    continue_text = pygame.image.load('images/continue.png')
    game_over_text = pygame.image.load('images/game_over.png')
    text_bubbles = [next_move_text, next_pokemon_text, exit_text, continue_text, game_over_text]
    help_text_number = 0
    turn_logged = False
    playing = True
    stop_that = False

    player_field = {
        "stealth rock": False,
        "spikes": 0,
        "toxic spikes": 0,
    }
    opponent_field = {
        "stealth rock": False,
        "spikes": 0,
        "toxic spikes": 0,
    }
    stealth_rock_sprite = pygame.image.load("images/stealth_rock.png")
    spike_sprite = pygame.image.load('images/triangle.png')

    @staticmethod
    def update(screen):
        Game.current_screen = Game.screens[Game.current_screen_number]
        Game.current_screen.Block_List.draw(screen)
        Button.update(screen, Game.current_screen.Button_List)
        Game.current_pokemon = Game.Pokemon_List[Game.current_pokemon_number]
        Game.opponent.pokemon = Game.Opponent_Pokemon_List[Game.current_opponent_number]
        Game.Opponent_Pokemon_List = Game.opponent.list
        Game.help_text = Game.text_bubbles[Game.help_text_number]
        if Game.current_screen_number == 2:
            Game.update_info(screen)
        elif Game.current_screen_number == 1:
            Game.show_stats(screen)
        elif Game.current_screen_number == 3:
            Game.options(screen)
        elif Game.current_screen_number == 4:
            Game.Gym_Leaders(screen)

    @staticmethod
    def update_info(screen):

        # sprites
        if Game.turn_index+1 == Game.current_turn:  
            pokemon, opponent = Game.current_pokemon, Game.opponent.pokemon
            pokemon_health, opponent_health = Game.current_pokemon.current_health, Game.opponent.pokemon.current_health

        else:
            pokemon, opponent = Game.current_sprites[0], Game.current_sprites[1]
            if Game.turn_index == 0:
                pokemon_health, opponent_health = pokemon.max_health, opponent.max_health
            else:
                pokemon_health, opponent_health = Game.current_sprites[2], Game.current_sprites[3]
        sprites = [
                [pokemon.back_image, (225, 250)],
                [opponent.front_image, (475, 50)],
                [pokemon.type.image, (495, 265)],
                [opponent.type.image, (75, 40)],
            ]
        if opponent.type2 != None:
            type2 = (opponent.type2.image, (107, 40))
            sprites.append(type2)
        if pokemon.type2 != None:
            type2 = (pokemon.type2.image, (527, 265))
            sprites.append(type2)

        help_text = [Game.help_text, (5, 300)]
        sprites.append(help_text)

        # text
        text = [
        ["%s" % Game.square_info[0], 125, 385],
        ["%s" % Game.square_info[1], 375, 385],
        ["%s" % Game.square_info[2], 125, 442],
        ["%s" % Game.square_info[3], 375, 442],
        #["%s" % Game.current_pokemon.name, 525, 250],
        #["%s" % Game.opponent.pokemon.name, 100, 25],
        #["%s/%s" % (int(math.floor(Game.current_pokemon.current_health)), Game.current_pokemon.max_health), 525, 315],
        #["%s" % Game.get_percent(Game.opponent.pokemon.current_health, Game.opponent.pokemon.max_health), 105, 90],
        #["hp:", 30, 70],
        #["hp:", 450, 295],
        ["%s" % pokemon.name, 525, 250],
        ["%s" % opponent.name, 100, 25],
        ["%s/%s" % (int(math.floor(pokemon_health)), pokemon.max_health), 525, 315],
        ["%s" % Game.get_percent(opponent_health, opponent.max_health), 105, 90],
        ["hp:", 30, 70],
        ["hp:", 450, 295],
        ]
        for item in text:
            Functions.text_to_screen(screen, item[0], item[1], item[2], 20)
        pokemon_hp = math.floor((pokemon_health / pokemon.max_health) * 110)
        opponent_hp = math.floor((opponent_health / opponent.max_health) * 110)
        # Check if all pokemon in party are fainted or not
        # Also display Pokeballs for each pokemon
        x = 0
        x_axis = 470
        Lose, Win = True, True
        Game.can_switch = False
        for pokemon in Game.Pokemon_List:
            pokeball = [Pokemon.Pokeball, (x_axis, 334)]
            sprites.append(pokeball)
            if pokemon != Game.current_pokemon:
                Game.Pokemon_Party[x] = pokemon
                x+=1
                if pokemon.current_health > 0:
                    Game.can_switch = True
            if pokemon.current_health > 0:
                Lose = False
            else:
                icon = [Pokemon.icon_x, (x_axis, 334)]
                sprites.append(icon)
            x_axis += 24
        x = 0
        x_axis = 50
        Game.opponent_can_switch = False
        for pokemon in Game.Opponent_Pokemon_List:
            pokeball = [Pokemon.Pokeball, (x_axis, 109)]
            sprites.append(pokeball)
            if pokemon != Game.opponent.pokemon:
                Game.Opponent_Party[x] = pokemon
                x+=1
                if pokemon.current_health > 0:
                    Game.opponent_can_switch = True
            if pokemon.current_health > 0:
                Win = False
            else:
                icon = [Pokemon.icon_x, (x_axis, 109)]
                sprites.append(icon)
            x_axis += 24

        # Show moves or team in the squares
        if not Game.show_party:
            Game.square_info = [Game.current_pokemon.move1.name, Game.current_pokemon.move2.name, Game.current_pokemon.move3.name, Game.current_pokemon.move4.name,]
            secondary_info = [
                ["power:", 185, 405],
                ["%s" % Game.current_pokemon.move1.power, 230, 405],
                ["power:", 435, 405],
                ["%s" % Game.current_pokemon.move2.power, 480, 405],
                ["power:", 185, 462],
                ["%s" % Game.current_pokemon.move3.power, 230, 462],
                ["power:", 435, 462],
                ["%s" % Game.current_pokemon.move4.power, 480, 462],
            ]
            info_sprites = [
                [Game.current_pokemon.move1.type.image, (50, 400)],
                [Game.current_pokemon.move1.contact_image, (100, 400)],
                [Game.current_pokemon.move2.type.image, (300, 400)],
                [Game.current_pokemon.move2.contact_image, (350, 400)],
                [Game.current_pokemon.move3.type.image, (50, 457)],
                [Game.current_pokemon.move3.contact_image, (100, 457)],
                [Game.current_pokemon.move4.type.image, (300, 457)],
                [Game.current_pokemon.move4.contact_image, (350, 457)],
            ]

        elif Game.show_party:
            Game.square_info = [Game.Pokemon_Party[0].name, Game.Pokemon_Party[1].name, Game.Pokemon_Party[2].name, Game.Pokemon_Party[3].name]
            secondary_info = [
                ["hp:", 160, 408],
                ["%s/%s" % (int(Game.Pokemon_Party[0].current_health), Game.Pokemon_Party[0].max_health), 210, 408],
                ["hp:", 410, 408],
                ["%s/%s" % (int(Game.Pokemon_Party[1].current_health), Game.Pokemon_Party[1].max_health), 460, 408],
                ["hp:", 160, 465],
                ["%s/%s" % (int(Game.Pokemon_Party[2].current_health), Game.Pokemon_Party[2].max_health), 210, 465],
                ["hp:", 410, 465],
                ["%s/%s" % (int(Game.Pokemon_Party[3].current_health), Game.Pokemon_Party[3].max_health), 460, 465],    
            ]
            info_sprites = [
                [Game.Pokemon_Party[0].type.image, (50, 400)],
                [Game.Pokemon_Party[1].type.image, (300, 400)],
                [Game.Pokemon_Party[2].type.image, (50, 457)],
                [Game.Pokemon_Party[3].type.image, (300, 457)],
            ]
            if Game.Pokemon_Party[0].type2 != None:
                sprite = (Game.Pokemon_Party[0].type2.image, (82, 400))
                sprites.append(sprite)
            if Game.Pokemon_Party[1].type2 != None:
                sprite = (Game.Pokemon_Party[1].type2.image, (332, 400))
                sprites.append(sprite)
            if Game.Pokemon_Party[2].type2 != None:
                sprite = (Game.Pokemon_Party[2].type2.image, (82, 457))
                sprites.append(sprite)
            if Game.Pokemon_Party[3].type2 != None:
                sprite = (Game.Pokemon_Party[3].type2.image, (332, 457))
                sprites.append(sprite)

        # Entry Hazards
        if Game.opponent_field["stealth rock"]:
            rock_icon = (Game.stealth_rock_sprite, (425, 100))
            sprites.append(rock_icon)
        if Game.player_field["stealth rock"]:
            rock_icon = (Game.stealth_rock_sprite, (350, 300))
            sprites.append(rock_icon)
        if Game.opponent_field["spikes"] > 0:
            x = 450
            for spike in range(Game.opponent_field["spikes"]):  
                spikes_icon = (Game.spike_sprite, (x, 150))
                sprites.append(spikes_icon)
                x+=25
        if Game.player_field["spikes"] > 0:
            x = 300
            for spike in range(Game.player_field["spikes"]):    
                spikes_icon = (Game.spike_sprite, (x, 340))
                sprites.append(spikes_icon)
                x+=25

        # Blitting the sprites
        for item in info_sprites:
            screen.blit(item[0], item[1])
        for item in secondary_info:
            Functions.text_to_screen(screen, item[0], item[1], item[2], 18)
        for item in sprites:
            screen.blit(item[0], item[1])

        #### Health Bars ###
        block_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
        health_bars = [
            [50, 65, 110, 12, RED],
            [470, 290, 110, 12, RED],
        ]
        for block in health_bars:
            new_block = Block(block[0], block[1], block[2], block[3], block[4])
            block_list.add(new_block)
        block_list.draw(screen)

        block_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
        # Health Bar Colors
        if 28 < pokemon_hp <= 55:
            pokemon_color = YELLOW
        elif 0 < pokemon_hp <= 28:
            pokemon_color = DARK_RED
        else:
            pokemon_color = BLUE
        if 28 < opponent_hp <= 55:
            opponent_color = YELLOW
        elif 0 < opponent_hp <= 28:
            opponent_color = DARK_RED
        else:
            opponent_color = BLUE
        health_bar_color = (25,25,25)
        blocks = [
            #[50, 65, 110, 12, RED],
            #[470, 290, 110, 12, RED],
            [470, 290, pokemon_hp, 12, pokemon_color],
            [50, 65, opponent_hp, 12, opponent_color],
            [160, 63, 6, 16, health_bar_color],
            [580, 288, 6, 16, health_bar_color],
            [48, 63, 2, 16, health_bar_color],
            [468, 288, 2, 16, health_bar_color],
            [48, 77, 112, 2, health_bar_color],
            [468, 302, 112, 2, health_bar_color],
            [48, 63, 112, 2, health_bar_color],
            [468, 288, 112, 2, health_bar_color],
        ]
        for block in blocks:
            new_block = Block(block[0], block[1], block[2], block[3], block[4])
            block_list.add(new_block)
        block_list.draw(screen)

        # Win or Lose
        if Win:
            Game.game_over(screen, Game.current_pokemon)
        if Lose:
            Game.game_over(screen, Game.opponent.pokemon)
        # Show the current turn info and pause the Game
        if Game.pause:
            if Game.playing:
                Game.help_text_number = 3
            """for item in Game.current_turn_text:
                Functions.text_to_screen(screen, item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3], item[4])"""
        if not Game.pause:
            Game.log_turn(False)
            Game.current_turn_text = set([])
            Game.first_move_done = False
            Game.second_move_done = False
            Game.text_y = 75
            Game.help_text_number = 0
            Game.turn_logged = False
            Game.stop_that = False
        # Check if a pokemon on the battlefield has fainted
        if math.floor(Game.current_pokemon.current_health) <= 0 or math.floor(Game.opponent.pokemon.current_health) <= 0:
            Game.Pokemon_Fainted = True
            Game.pause = True
            if Game.current_pokemon.current_health <= 0:
                Game.show_party = True
                Game.current_pokemon.fainted = True
                Game.current_pokemon.current_health = 0
                Game.help_text_number = 1
            if Game.opponent.pokemon.current_health <= 0:
                Game.opponent.pokemon.fainted = True
                Game.opponent.pokemon.current_health = 0

        # Tell player a Pokemon has fainted
        if Game.Pokemon_Fainted:
            Game.pause = True
            if Game.current_pokemon.fainted and not Game.opponent.pokemon.fainted:
                if not Game.stop_that:  
                    dead_text = ("%s died!" % Game.current_pokemon.name, 150, Game.text_y, 25, RED)
                    Game.battle_text[Game.current_turn - 1].add(dead_text)
                    Game.stop_that = True
            elif Game.opponent.pokemon.fainted and not Game.current_pokemon.fainted:
                dead_text = ("%s died!" % Game.opponent.pokemon.name, 150, Game.text_y, 25, BLUE)
                Game.battle_text[Game.current_turn - 1].add(dead_text)
                if not Game.switching:
                    Game.switch_opponent(True)
                else:
                    #if not Game.going_to_switch:
                    #   Game.text_y += 35
                    Game.going_to_switch = True

            elif Game.current_pokemon.fainted and Game.opponent.pokemon.fainted:
                dead_text = ("%s died!" % Game.current_pokemon.name, 150, Game.text_y+35, 25, RED)
                Game.battle_text[Game.current_turn - 1].add(dead_text)
                dead_text = ("%s died!" % Game.opponent.pokemon.name, 150, Game.text_y, 25, BLUE)
                Game.battle_text[Game.current_turn - 1].add(dead_text)

        # Show specific turn info on the side
        if Game.current_turn > 0:
            for item in Game.battle_text[Game.turn_index]:
                try:
                    Functions.text_to_screen(screen, item[0], 800, item[2], 20, item[4])
                    y += 35
                except:
                    print item
            Game.current_sprites = Game.battle_sprites[Game.turn_index+1]


        ### U-turn/Volt-Switch ###
        if Game.switching:
            Game.show_party = True
            Game.help_text_number = 1
        # Opponent U-turn/Volt-switch
        if Game.opponent_switching:
            switch = computer_move.best_switch(Game.current_pokemon, Game.Opponent_Party)
            Game.switch_move(Game.opponent.pokemon, switch)

        # Switch after dying from U-turn/Volt-switch
        if not Game.switching and Game.going_to_switch:
            Game.switch_opponent()

        # Game Over help text
        if not Game.playing:
            Game.help_text_number = 4

        # After Turn
        """if Game.second_move_done:
            if Game.current_pokemon.speed > Game.opponent.pokemon.speed:    
                Game.after_turn_item(Game.current_pokemon)
                Game.after_turn_item(Game.opponent.pokemon)
            else:
                Game.after_turn_item(Game.opponent.pokemon)
                Game.after_turn_item(Game.current_pokemon)
            Game.second_move_done = False"""

    @staticmethod
    def show_stats(screen):
        text = [
        ["%s" % Game.current_pokemon.max_health, 515, 150],
        ["%s" % Game.current_pokemon.attack, 515, 210],
        ["%s" % Game.current_pokemon.defense, 515, 270],
        ["%s" % Game.current_pokemon.special_attack, 515, 330],
        ["%s" % Game.current_pokemon.special_defense, 515, 390],
        ["%s" % Game.current_pokemon.speed, 515, 450],
        ]

        for item in text:
            Functions.text_to_screen(screen, item[0], item[1], item[2])

        buttons = [
        ["%s" % Game.current_pokemon.name, 75, 25, 250, 30, BLUE, BLUE, None],
        ["Type: %s" % Game.current_pokemon.type.name, 375, 5, 200, 30, BLUE, BLUE, None],
        #move1 & stats
        ["Move 1: %s" % Game.current_pokemon.move1.name, 25, 75, 275, 30, BLUE, BLUE, None],
        ["Type: %s" % Game.current_pokemon.move1.type.name, 25, 107, 250, 30, DODGER_BLUE, BLUE, None],
        ["Power:%s" % Game.current_pokemon.move1.power, 5, 142, 125, 30, DODGER_BLUE, BLUE, None],
        ["Contact: %s" % Game.current_pokemon.move1.contact, 135, 142, 200, 30, DODGER_BLUE, BLUE, None],
        # move 2 & stats
        ["Move 2: %s" % Game.current_pokemon.move2.name, 25, 175, 275, 30, BLUE, BLUE, None],
        ["Type: %s" % Game.current_pokemon.move2.type.name, 25, 207, 250, 30, DODGER_BLUE, BLUE, None],
        ["Power:%s" % Game.current_pokemon.move2.power, 5, 242, 125, 30, DODGER_BLUE, BLUE, None],
        ["Contact: %s" % Game.current_pokemon.move2.contact, 135, 242, 200, 30, DODGER_BLUE, BLUE, None],
        # move 3 & stats
        ["Move 3: %s" % Game.current_pokemon.move3.name, 25, 275, 275, 30, BLUE, BLUE, None],
        ["Type: %s" % Game.current_pokemon.move3.type.name, 25, 307, 250, 30, DODGER_BLUE, BLUE, None],
        ["Power:%s" % Game.current_pokemon.move3.power, 5, 342, 125, 30, DODGER_BLUE, BLUE, None],
        ["Contact: %s" % Game.current_pokemon.move3.contact, 135, 342, 200, 30, DODGER_BLUE, BLUE, None],
        # move 4 & stats
        ["Move 4: %s" % Game.current_pokemon.move4.name, 25, 375, 275, 30, BLUE, BLUE, None],
        ["Type: %s" % Game.current_pokemon.move4.type.name, 25, 407, 250, 30, DODGER_BLUE, BLUE, None],
        ["Power:%s" % Game.current_pokemon.move4.power, 5, 442, 125, 30, DODGER_BLUE, BLUE, None],
        ["Contact: %s" % Game.current_pokemon.move4.contact, 135, 442, 200, 30, DODGER_BLUE, BLUE, None],
        # points
        ["Points: %s" % Game.current_pokemon.points, 400, 75, 150, 30, BRIGHT_BLUE, BRIGHT_BLUE, None],
        ["Health", 340, 135, 100, 30, BLUE, BLUE, None],
        ["Attack", 340, 195, 100, 30, BLUE, BLUE, None],
        ["Defense", 340, 255, 100, 30, BLUE, BLUE, None],
        ["Sp.Atk", 340, 315, 100, 30, BLUE, BLUE, None],
        ["Sp.Def", 340, 375, 100, 30, BLUE, BLUE, None],
        ["Speed", 340, 435, 100, 30, BLUE, BLUE, None],
        ]
        if Game.current_pokemon.type2 != None:
            type2 = ["%s" % Game.current_pokemon.type2.name, 375, 35, 200, 30, BLUE, BLUE, None]
            buttons.append(type2)
        button_list = []
        for item in buttons:
            button = Button(item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3], item[4], item[5], item[6], item[7])
            button_list.append(button)

        base_stats = [
        ["%s" % Game.current_pokemon.base_health, 460, 150],
        ["%s" % Game.current_pokemon.base_attack, 460, 210],
        ["%s" % Game.current_pokemon.base_defense, 460, 270],
        ["%s" % Game.current_pokemon.base_special_attack, 460, 330],
        ["%s" % Game.current_pokemon.base_special_defense, 460, 390],
        ["%s" % Game.current_pokemon.base_speed, 460, 450],
        ]

        for item in base_stats:
            Functions.text_to_screen(screen, item[0], item[1], item[2], 20)

        Button.update(screen, button_list)
        Pokemon.update()

        Game.current_pokemon.move1 = Game.current_pokemon.move_list[Game.current_pokemon.move1_number]
        Game.current_pokemon.move2 = Game.current_pokemon.move_list[Game.current_pokemon.move2_number]
        Game.current_pokemon.move3 = Game.current_pokemon.move_list[Game.current_pokemon.move3_number]
        Game.current_pokemon.move4 = Game.current_pokemon.move_list[Game.current_pokemon.move4_number]

        Game.current_pokemon.move_set[0] = Game.current_pokemon.move1
        Game.current_pokemon.move_set[1] = Game.current_pokemon.move2
        Game.current_pokemon.move_set[2] = Game.current_pokemon.move3
        Game.current_pokemon.move_set[3] = Game.current_pokemon.move4

    @staticmethod
    def options(screen):
        button_list = []
        y = 100
        for pokemon in Game.opponent.list:
            button = Button("%s" % pokemon.name, 335, y, 300, 30, RED, RED, None)
            button_list.append(button)
            y += 50
        y = 100
        for pokemon in Game.Pokemon_List:
            button = Button("%s" % pokemon.name, 5, y, 300, 30, BLUE, BLUE, None)
            button_list.append(button)
            y += 50

        text = [
        ["Your Team", 155, 50],
        ["Opponent Team", 485, 50],
        ["%s Pokemon" % len(Pokemon.All_Pokemon), 300, 25],
        ["%s" % len(Opponent.All_Pokemon), 500, 25],
        ]

        for item in text:
            Functions.text_to_screen(screen, item[0], item[1], item[2])
        Button.update(screen, button_list)

    @staticmethod
    def Gym_Leaders(screen):
        text = [
            ["Gym Leaders Room", 325, 25],
            ["Click to Challenge!", 325, 50]
        ]
        for item in text:
            Functions.text_to_screen(screen, item[0], item[1], item[2])

    @staticmethod
    def reset():

        Game.pause = False
        Game.current_pokemon_number = 0
        Game.current_opponent_number = 0
        for pokemon in Game.Pokemon_List:
            pokemon.current_health = pokemon.max_health
            pokemon.fainted = False
            pokemon.first_turn = True
        for pokemon in Game.Opponent_Pokemon_List:
            pokemon.current_health = pokemon.max_health
            pokemon.fainted = False
            pokemon.first_turn = True
        Game.current_turn_text = set([])
        Game.show_party = False
        Game.Pokemon_Fainted = False
        Game.battle_text[:] = []
        Game.turn_index = -1
        Game.current_turn = 0
        Game.switching = False
        Game.opponent_switching = False
        Game.first_move_done = False
        Game.second_move_done = False
        Game.going_to_switch = False
        Game.text_y = 75
        Game.help_text_number = 0
        Game.turn_logged = False
        Game.playing = True
        Game.stop_that = False
        Game.battle_sprites[:] = []
        Game.current_sprites = [Game.Pokemon_List[0], Game.Opponent_Pokemon_List[0]]
        Game.battle_sprites.append(Game.current_sprites)
        Game.player_field["stealth rock"] = False
        Game.opponent_field["stealth rock"] = False
        Game.player_field["spikes"] = 0
        Game.opponent_field["spikes"] = 0

    @staticmethod
    def attack(attacker, defender, move, y):
        type_advantage = Game.type_advantage(defender, move)
        power = Game.damage_calc(attacker, defender, move, type_advantage)
        x = y
        damage = None
        if defender.current_health - power > 0 and type_advantage > 0:
            defender.current_health -= power
            damage = power
        elif defender.current_health - power <= 0:
            damage = defender.current_health
            defender.current_health = 0
        x+=35
        Game.text_y += 35
        if type_advantage == 2 or type_advantage == 4:
            type_advantage_text = ["It's super effective!", 375, y+35]
        elif type_advantage == 0.5 or type_advantage == 0.25:
            type_advantage_text = ["It's not very effective...", 375, y+35]
        elif type_advantage == 0:
            type_advantage_text = ["It didn't do anything...", 375, y+35]
        else:
            type_advantage_text = ""
            x -= 35
            Game.text_y -= 35
        last_text = ""
        if attacker == Game.current_pokemon:
            if type_advantage > 0:
                last_text = "%s lost %s HP!" % (defender.name, Game.get_percent(damage, defender.max_health))
            color = BLUE
        elif attacker == Game.opponent.pokemon:
            if type_advantage > 0:
                last_text = "%s lost %s HP!" % (defender.name, int(math.floor(damage)))
            color = DARK_RED
        text = [
        ["%s used %s!" % (attacker.name, move.name), 375, y],
        ["%s" % last_text, 375, x+35]
        ]
        if type_advantage != 1:
            text.append(type_advantage_text)
        for item in text:
            Game.current_turn_text.add((item[0], item[1], item[2], 20, color))
        attacker.first_turn = False
        Game.text_y += 70
        return damage

    @staticmethod
    def do_moves(move):
        Game.pause = True
        opponent_move = Game.opponent_move()        
        if not isinstance(move, int) and not isinstance(opponent_move, int):    
            if move.priority == opponent_move.priority: 
                if Game.current_pokemon.speed > Game.opponent.pokemon.speed:
                    first = Game.current_pokemon
                    second = Game.opponent.pokemon

                elif Game.opponent.pokemon.speed >= Game.current_pokemon.speed:
                    first = Game.opponent.pokemon
                    second = Game.current_pokemon

            elif move.priority > opponent_move.priority:
                first = Game.current_pokemon
                second = Game.opponent.pokemon

            elif move.priority < opponent_move.priority:
                first = Game.opponent.pokemon
                second = Game.current_pokemon

            if first == Game.current_pokemon:
                move1 = move
                move2 = opponent_move
            elif first == Game.opponent.pokemon:
                move1 = opponent_move
                move2 = move

            can_move = True
            if move1.effect != None:
                can_move = Game.move_with_effect(first, second, move1, move2, Game.text_y)
            else:
                Game.attack(first, second, move1, Game.text_y)
            #Game.text_y += 175
            Game.first_move_done = True
            if (second.current_health > 0 and can_move):
                if not Game.switching and not Game.opponent_switching:
                    if move2.effect != None:
                        Game.move_with_effect(second, first, move2, 1, Game.text_y)
                    else:
                        Game.attack(second, first, move2, Game.text_y)
                    Game.second_move_done = True
                elif Game.switching or Game.opponent_switching: 
                    Game.second_move_info = (second, first, move2, Game.text_y)

        elif isinstance(move, int) and isinstance(opponent_move, int):
            if Game.current_pokemon.speed > Game.opponent.pokemon.speed:
                Game.switch_pokemon(Game.current_pokemon, move, Game.text_y)
                Game.switch_pokemon(Game.opponent.pokemon, opponent_move, Game.text_y)
            elif Game.current_pokemon.speed <= Game.opponent.pokemon.speed:
                Game.switch_pokemon(Game.opponent.pokemon, opponent_move, Game.text_y)
                Game.switch_pokemon(Game.current_pokemon, move, Game.text_y)
            Game.second_move_done = True

        else:
            if isinstance(move, int):
                defender = Game.switch_pokemon(Game.current_pokemon, move, Game.text_y)
                Game.first_move_done = True
                if opponent_move.effect == None:    
                    Game.attack(Game.opponent.pokemon, defender, opponent_move, Game.text_y)
                elif opponent_move.effect != None:
                    Game.move_with_effect(Game.opponent.pokemon, defender, opponent_move, move, Game.text_y)
                Game.second_move_done = True
            elif not isinstance(move, int):
                defender = Game.switch_pokemon(Game.opponent.pokemon, opponent_move, Game.text_y)
                Game.first_move_done = True
                if move.effect == None: 
                    Game.attack(Game.current_pokemon, defender, move, Game.text_y)
                elif move.effect != None:
                    Game.move_with_effect(Game.current_pokemon, defender, move, opponent_move, Game.text_y)
                Game.second_move_done = True

        if not Game.turn_logged:    
            Game.log_turn()
            #Game.log_sprites(Game.current_pokemon, Game.opponent.pokemon)
        #else:
        #   Game.log_turn(False)

    @staticmethod
    def damage_calc(attacker, defender, move, type_advantage):
        # Damage = (0.44*(attack/defense)*move power)*modifier
        # Modifier = STAB * Type effectiveness * other(items, abilities)
        if move.contact == "physical":
            attack = attacker.attack
            defense = defender.defense
        elif move.contact == "special":
            attack = attacker.special_attack
            defense = defender.special_defense
        power = move.power

        #STAB
        STAB = 1
        if attacker.type.name == move.type.name:
            STAB = 1.5
        if attacker.type2 != None and STAB == 1:
            if attacker.type2.name == move.type.name:
                STAB = 1.5
        # Damage calculation
        damage = math.floor((0.2 * (attack / defense) * power + 2) * (type_advantage * STAB))
        return damage

    @staticmethod
    def type_advantage(defender, move):
        type_advantage = 1

        for weakness in defender.type.weakness_list:
            if move.type.name == weakness:
                type_advantage = 2
                break
        for resist in defender.type.resist_list:
            if move.type.name == resist:
                type_advantage = 0.5
                break
        for immune in defender.type.immune_list:
            if move.type.name == immune:
                type_advantage = 0
                break

        if defender.type2 != None and type_advantage > 0:
            for weakness in defender.type2.weakness_list:
                if move.type.name == weakness:
                    if type_advantage == 1:
                        type_advantage = 2
                    elif type_advantage == 2:
                        type_advantage = 4
                    elif type_advantage == 0.5:
                        type_advantage = 1
                    break
            for resist in defender.type2.resist_list:
                if move.type.name == resist:
                    if type_advantage == 1:
                        type_advantage = 0.5
                    elif type_advantage == 2:
                        type_advantage = 1
                    elif type_advantage == 0.5:
                        type_advantage = 0.25
                    break
            for immune in defender.type2.immune_list:
                if move.type.name == immune:
                    type_advantage = 0
                    break

        return type_advantage

    @staticmethod
    def get_percent(numerator, denominator):
        number = int(round((numerator/denominator)*100))
        percent = ("%s%%" % number)
        return percent

    @staticmethod
    def switch_pokemon(pokemon, pokemon_number, y):
        if pokemon == Game.current_pokemon:
            old = Game.current_pokemon
            new = Game.Pokemon_Party[pokemon_number]
            new_number = Game.Pokemon_List.index(new)
            Game.current_pokemon_number = new_number
            Game.show_party = False
            poke = Game.opponent.pokemon
            color = GREEN
            field = Game.player_field
        else:
            old = Game.opponent.pokemon
            new = Game.Opponent_Party[pokemon_number]
            new_number = Game.Opponent_Pokemon_List.index(new)
            Game.current_opponent_number = new_number
            poke = Game.current_pokemon
            color = YELLOW
            Game.switched_in = True
            field = Game.opponent_field
        text = [
        ["%s come back!" % old.name, 375, y],
        ["Go %s!" % new.name, 375, y+35]
        ]
        for item in text:
            Game.current_turn_text.add((item[0], item[1], item[2], 20, color))
        new.first_turn = True
        Game.switching = False
        Game.text_y += 35
        Game.entry_hazard_damage(new, field)
        Game.text_y += 35
        return new

    @staticmethod
    def send_in_pokemon(pokemon_number):
        if Game.Pokemon_Party[pokemon_number].current_health > 0:
            Game.text_y += 35
            Game.pause = True
            old = Game.current_pokemon
            new = Game.Pokemon_Party[pokemon_number]
            new_number = Game.Pokemon_List.index(new)
            Game.current_pokemon_number = new_number
            text = ("Go %s" % new.name, 150, Game.text_y, 20, GREEN)
            Game.battle_text[Game.current_turn - 1].add(text)
            Game.current_turn_text.add(text)
            Game.entry_hazard_damage(new, Game.player_field)
            Game.Pokemon_Fainted = False
            Game.show_party = False
            new.first_turn = True
            Game.text_y += 35

    @staticmethod
    def switch_opponent(dead=False):
        #if not Game.switching: 
        next_switch = computer_move.best_switch(Game.current_pokemon, Game.Opponent_Party, dead)
        Game.send_in_opponent(next_switch)

    @staticmethod
    def game_over(screen, winner):
        Game.pause = True
        Game.show_party = False
        Game.playing = False
        Game.help_text_number = 4
        if winner == Game.current_pokemon:
            text = ("You win!", 150, 425, 30, WHITE)
        elif winner == Game.opponent.pokemon:
            text = ("You are out of Pokemon!", 150, 425, 30, WHITE)
        Game.battle_text[Game.current_turn - 1].add(text)

    @staticmethod
    def send_in_opponent(pokemon_number):
        if isinstance(pokemon_number, int):
            if Game.Opponent_Party[pokemon_number].current_health > 0:
                #
                old = Game.opponent.pokemon
                new = Game.Opponent_Party[pokemon_number]
                new_number = Game.Opponent_Pokemon_List.index(new)
                Game.current_opponent_number = new_number

                Game.text_y += 35
                text = ("Go %s" % new.name, 150, Game.text_y, 20, YELLOW)
                Game.current_turn_text.add(text)
                Game.battle_text[Game.current_turn - 1].add(text)

                Game.entry_hazard_damage(new, Game.opponent_field)
                Game.Pokemon_Fainted = False
                Game.show_party = False
                Game.switched_in = True
                new.first_turn = True
                Game.going_to_switch = False
                Game.text_y += 35

    @staticmethod
    def log_turn(next_turn=True):
        #turn_text = Game.current_turn_text
        if next_turn:
            Game.turn_index = Game.current_turn 
            Game.current_turn += 1
            turn_number = ("Turn %s" % Game.current_turn, 800, 40, 30, (255,255,255))
            Game.turn_text.add(turn_number)
            Game.battle_text.append(Game.turn_text)
            Game.turn_logged = True
            Game.log_sprites(Game.current_pokemon, Game.opponent.pokemon)
        else:
            for text in Game.turn_text:
                Game.battle_text[Game.current_turn-1].add(text)
        for text in Game.current_turn_text:
            Game.turn_text.add(text)
        Game.turn_text = set([])

    @staticmethod
    def log_sprites(pokemon, opponent):
        Game.current_turn_sprites = (pokemon, opponent, pokemon.current_health, opponent.current_health)
        Game.battle_sprites.append(Game.current_turn_sprites)

    @staticmethod
    def move_with_effect(attacker, defender, move, defender_move, y):
        can_move = True
        if attacker == Game.current_pokemon:
            attacker_color = BLUE
        elif attacker == Game.opponent.pokemon:
            attacker_color = DARK_RED
        if move.power > 0:  

            if move.effect == "flinch": 
                if attacker.first_turn:
                    Game.attack(attacker, defender, move, y)
                    if defender.current_health > 0 and not isinstance(defender_move, int):
                        flinch_text = ("%s flinched!" % defender.name, 375, y+110, 25, DARK_RED)
                        Game.current_turn_text.add(flinch_text) 
                        can_move = False
                else:
                    flinch_text = ("%s used %s..." % (attacker.name, move.name), 375, y, 25, attacker_color)
                    flinch_text2 = ("But it failed!", 375, y+35, 25, attacker_color)
                    Game.current_turn_text.add(flinch_text2)
                    Game.current_turn_text.add(flinch_text)
            elif move.effect == "sucker_punch":
                if isinstance(defender_move, int):
                    sucker_text = ("%s used %s..." % (attacker.name, move.name), 375, y, 25, attacker_color)
                    sucker_text2 = ("But it failed!", 375, y+35, 25, attacker_color)
                    Game.current_turn_text.add(sucker_text)
                    Game.current_turn_text.add(sucker_text2)
                else:
                    Game.attack(attacker, defender, move, y)
                Game.text_y -= 70
            elif move.effect == "recoil":
                damage = Game.attack(attacker, defender, move, y)
                Game.text_y -= 35
                if damage != None:  
                    recoil_damage = math.floor(damage/3)
                    attacker.current_health -= recoil_damage
                    recoil_text = ("%s was hurt by recoil!" % attacker.name, 375, y+105, 25, attacker_color)
                    Game.current_turn_text.add(recoil_text)
                if attacker.current_health <= 0:
                    attacker.current_health = 0 
            elif move.effect == "drain":
                damage = Game.attack(attacker, defender, move, y)
                Game.text_y -= 35
                if damage != None:
                    drain_damage = math.floor(damage/2)
                    attacker.current_health += drain_damage
                    drain_text = ("%s drained some health!" % attacker.name, 375, y+105, 25, GREEN)
                    Game.current_turn_text.add(drain_text)
                if attacker.current_health > attacker.max_health:
                    attacker.current_health = attacker.max_health
            elif move.effect == "switch":
                damage = Game.attack(attacker, defender, move, y)
                if damage:
                    if Game.can_switch and attacker == Game.current_pokemon:
                        Game.switching = True
                        if defender.current_health <= 0:
                            Game.going_to_switch = True
                    elif Game.opponent_can_switch and attacker == Game.opponent.pokemon:
                        Game.opponent_switching = True
                if Game.first_move_done:
                    Game.second_move_done = True
                else:
                    Game.first_move_done = True
                if isinstance(defender_move, int):
                    Game.second_move_done = True
                    Game.second_move_info = None
            Game.text_y += 70
        else:
            can_move = Game.non_damaging_move(attacker, defender, move, defender_move, y, attacker_color)
        return can_move

    @staticmethod
    def non_damaging_move(pokemon, opponent, move, opponent_move, y, color):
        can_move = True
        if pokemon == Game.current_pokemon:
            field = Game.opponent_field
        elif pokemon == Game.opponent.pokemon:
            field = Game.player_field
        text = ("%s used %s!" % (pokemon.name, move.name), 375, y, 25, color)
        Game.current_turn_text.add(text)
        Game.text_y += 35
        if move.effect == "stealth rock":
            if field["stealth rock"]:
                failed_text = ("But it failed!", 375, y+35, 25, YELLOW)
                Game.current_turn_text.add(failed_text)
                Game.text_y += 35
            field["stealth rock"] = True
        elif move.effect == "spikes":
            if field["spikes"] < 3:
                field["spikes"] += 1
            else:
                failed_text = ("But it failed!", 375, y+35, 25, YELLOW)
                Game.current_turn_text.add(failed_text)
                Game.text_y += 35

        return can_move

    @staticmethod
    def switch_move(pokemon, switch_number):
        if Game.second_move_info != None:
            y = 175
        else:
            y = 360
        Game.text_y += 35
        new = Game.switch_pokemon(pokemon, switch_number, Game.text_y)

        if (Game.second_move_info != None and not Game.second_move_done):
            if Game.second_move_info[2].effect == None:
                Game.attack(Game.second_move_info[0], new, Game.second_move_info[2], Game.text_y)
            elif Game.second_move_info[2].effect != None:
                Game.move_with_effect(Game.second_move_info[0], new, Game.second_move_info[2], 1, Game.text_y)
            Game.second_move_info = None

        Game.switching = False
        Game.opponent_switching = False

        #if Game.second_move_info == None:
        Game.log_turn(False)

    @staticmethod
    def entry_hazard_damage(switch, field):
        percent = math.floor(switch.max_health * 0.125)
        if field["stealth rock"]:
            Game.text_y += 35
            TA = Game.type_advantage(switch, stealth_rock_damage)
            damage = math.floor(percent * TA)
            switch.current_health -= damage
            text = ("%s was hurt by Stealth Rock!" % switch.name, 150, Game.text_y, 20, YELLOW)
            Game.current_turn_text.add(text)
            Game.battle_text[Game.current_turn - 1].add(text)
        if field["spikes"] > 0 and (switch.type != Flying and switch.type2 != Flying):
            Game.text_y += 35
            if field["spikes"] == 2:
                percent = math.floor(switch.max_health * 0.1667)
            elif field["spikes"] == 3:
                percent = math.floor(switch.max_health * 0.25)
            switch.current_health -= percent
            text = ("%s was hurt by Spikes!" % switch.name, 150, Game.text_y, 20, YELLOW)
            Game.current_turn_text.add(text)
            Game.battle_text[Game.current_turn - 1].add(text)

    @staticmethod
    def after_turn_item(pokemon):
        pokemon = pokemon
        if pokemon == Game.current_pokemon:
            color = GREEN
        else:
            color = YELLOW
        if pokemon.item != None and pokemon.current_health > 0: 
            if pokemon.item.name == "Leftovers" and pokemon.current_health < pokemon.max_health:
                gained = math.floor(pokemon.max_health * 0.0625)    
                pokemon.current_health += gained
                if pokemon.current_health > pokemon.max_health:
                    pokemon.current_health = pokemon.max_health
                gained_text = ("%s ate some Leftovers" % pokemon.name, 375, Game.text_y, 25, color)
                Game.current_turn_text.add(gained_text)
                Game.text_y += 35
        Game.log_turn(False)

    @staticmethod
    def opponent_move():
        opponent = Game.opponent.pokemon
        pokemon = Game.current_pokemon
        strongest_move = computer_move.opponent_move(pokemon, opponent)
        type_advantage = computer_move.move_type_advantage(pokemon, strongest_move)
        damage = Game.damage_calc(opponent, pokemon, strongest_move, type_advantage)
        switch = False
        kill = False
        best_switch = Game.Opponent_Party[computer_move.best_switch(pokemon, Game.Opponent_Party)]
        test = computer_move.who_wins(pokemon, opponent)
        if computer_move.best_switch(pokemon, Game.Opponent_Party): 
            if test == "loses":# and pokemon.base_speed > opponent.base_speed:
                switch = True
        """if best_switch.current_health > 0:
            offense_advantage, defense_advantage = computer_move.pokemon_type_advantage(pokemon, opponent)
            offense_advantage2, defense_advantage2 = computer_move.pokemon_type_advantage(opponent, pokemon)
            pokemon_type_advantage = (offense_advantage2 * defense_advantage2) / 2
            opponent_type_advantage = (offense_advantage * defense_advantage) / 2
            if (offense_advantage < offense_advantage2 and defense_advantage < defense_advantage2) and (pokemon.speed > opponent.speed):    
                switch = True"""
        if pokemon.current_health - damage <= 0 and pokemon.speed < opponent.speed:
            switch = False
            kill = True
        minimum = Game.current_pokemon.max_health / 4
        if (damage >= minimum and not switch) or Game.switched_in:
            opponent_move = strongest_move
            Game.switched_in = False
        else:
            opponent_move = computer_move.best_switch(pokemon, Game.Opponent_Party)
        test_move = computer_move.stay_alive(pokemon, opponent, Game.Opponent_Party)
        if test_move and not kill:
            opponent_move = test_move
        #return spikes
        return opponent_move
```

Are there better ways I could handle the moves and maybe make a `turn()` method? I plan on working on this project for a long time so I want to make it better. There are other Pokemon type battle questions out there but I feel this game is more complex than most.

[Video of the program](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BH0BeizYrn0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- if you use variable/attibute names like move1 or type2 it is almost always a sign that it wants to be a list (moves, types)

  ```
  sprites = [
          [pokemon.back_image, (225, 250)],
          [opponent.front_image, (475, 50)],
          [pokemon.type.image, (495, 265)],
          [opponent.type.image, (75, 40)],
      ]
  if opponent.type2 != None:
      type2 = (opponent.type2.image, (107, 40))
      sprites.append(type2)
  if pokemon.type2 != None:
      type2 = (pokemon.type2.image, (527, 265))
      sprites.append(type2)
  ```

  ```
  sprites = [
          [pokemon.back_image, (225, 250)],
          [opponent.front_image, (475, 50)],
      ]
  for current_pokemon,locations in [
          (pokemon,[(495, 265),(527, 265)]),
          (opponent,[(75, 40),(107, 40)])
          ]:
      for type,location in zip(current_pokemon.types,locations):
          sprites.append([(type.image,location)]
  ```
- use list literals, instead of:

  ```
  screens = []
  screens.append(home_screen)
  screens.append(team_builder_screen)
  screens.append(play_screen)
  screens.append(options_screen)
  screens.append(gym_leaders_screen)
  ```

  use:

  ```
  screens = [
      home_screen,
      team_builder_screen,
      play_screen,
      options_screen,
      gym_leaders_screen
      ]
  ```
- misleading variable name: 
  next_move_text is actually an image
- avoid repetition at almost all costs
  let the computer do the repetition
  repeated code makes it much harder to change/improve code
  whenever there are multiple lines after each other that are almost the same,
  you found a place to improve

  ```
  next_move_text = pygame.image.load('images/next_move.png')
  next_pokemon_text = pygame.image.load('images/next_pokemon.png')
  exit_text = pygame.image.load('images/exit_text.png')
  continue_text = pygame.image.load('images/continue.png')
  game_over_text = pygame.image.load('images/game_over.png')
  text_bubbles = [next_move_text, next_pokemon_text, exit_text, continue_text, game_over_text]
  ```

  to

  ```
  image_filename_list = [
      'images/next_move.png',
      'images/next_pokemon.png',
      'images/exit_text.png',
      'images/continue.png',
      'images/game_over.png',
  ]
  text_bubbles = [pygame.image.load(filename) for file_name in image_filename_list]
  ```

  ```
  player_field = {
      "stealth rock": False,
      "spikes": 0,
      "toxic spikes": 0,
  }
  opponent_field = {
      "stealth rock": False,
      "spikes": 0,
      "toxic spikes": 0,
  }
  ```

  to

  ```
  def get_empty_field():
      return {
          "stealth rock": False,
          "spikes": 0,
          "toxic spikes": 0,
      }
  player_field = get_empty_field()
  opponent_field = get_empty_field()
  ```

  ```
  x_axis = 470
  Lose, Win = True, True
  Game.can_switch = False
  for pokemon in Game.Pokemon_List:
      pokeball = [Pokemon.Pokeball, (x_axis, 334)]
      sprites.append(pokeball)
      if pokemon != Game.current_pokemon:
          Game.Pokemon_Party[x] = pokemon
          x+=1
          if pokemon.current_health > 0:
              Game.can_switch = True
      if pokemon.current_health > 0:
          Lose = False
      else:
          icon = [Pokemon.icon_x, (x_axis, 334)]
          sprites.append(icon)
      x_axis += 24
  x = 0
  x_axis = 50
  Game.opponent_can_switch = False
  for pokemon in Game.Opponent_Pokemon_List:
      pokeball = [Pokemon.Pokeball, (x_axis, 109)]
      sprites.append(pokeball)
      if pokemon != Game.opponent.pokemon:
          Game.Opponent_Party[x] = pokemon
          x+=1
          if pokemon.current_health > 0:
              Game.opponent_can_switch = True
      if pokemon.current_health > 0:
          Win = False
      else:
          icon = [Pokemon.icon_x, (x_axis, 109)]
          sprites.append(icon)
      x_axis += 24
  ```

  to

  ```
  def check_pokemon_party(x_axis,y_axis,pokemons,current_pokemon,pokemon_party):
      party_defeated = True
      can_switch = False
      for pokemon in pokemons:
          pokeball = [Pokemon.Pokeball, (x_axis, y_axis)]
          sprites.append(pokeball)
          if pokemon != current_pokemon:
              pokemon_party[x] = pokemon
              x+=1
              if pokemon.current_health > 0:
                  can_switch = True
          if pokemon.current_health > 0:
              party_defeated = False
          else:
              icon = [Pokemon.icon_x, (x_axis, y_axis)]
              sprites.append(icon)
          x_axis += 24
      return party_alive,can_switch

  Lose, Game.can_switch = check_pokemon_party(
      470,
      334,
      Game.Pokemon_List,
      Game.current_pokemon,
      Game.Pokemon_Party
      )
  Win, Game.opponent_can_switch = check_pokemon_party(
      50,
      109,
      Game.Opponent_Pokemon_List,
      Game.opponent.pokemon,
      Game.Opponent_Party
      )
  ```
- dont use an index to remember the current_item but use the item itself (unneeded complexity):

  ```
  Game.current_pokemon_number = new_number
  ```

  to

  ```
  Game.current_pokemon = Game.Pokemon_List[new_number]
  ```

  ```
  Game.help_text_number = 3
  ```

  to

  ```
  Game.help_text = Game.text_bubbles[3]
  ```
- using a dictionary instead of a list can make things much more readable:

  ```
  image_filename_list = [
  'images/next_move.png',
  'images/next_pokemon.png',
  'images/exit_text.png',
  'images/continue.png',
  'images/game_over.png',
  ]
  text_bubbles = [pygame.image.load(filename) for file_name in image_filename_list]
  ...
  Game.help_text = Game.text_bubbles[3]
  ```

  ```
  image_names = ['next_move', 'next_pokemon', 'exit_text', 'continue', 'game_over']
  text_bubbles = {
  name: pygame.image.load('images/{}.png'.format(name)) for name in image_names
  }
  ...
  Game.help_text = Game.text_bubbles['exit_text']
  ```
- use polymorphism instead of 'if' in some cases:

  ```
  if Game.current_screen_number == 2:
  Game.update_info(screen)
  elif Game.current_screen_number == 1:
  Game.show_stats(screen)
  elif Game.current_screen_number == 3:
  Game.options(screen)
  elif Game.current_screen_number == 4:
  Game.Gym_Leaders(screen)
  ```

  to

  ```
  class InfoScreen():
  def draw(game):
      #draw screen
  class StatScreen():
  def draw(game):
      #draw screen
  ...
  Game.current_screen = InfoScreen()
  Game.current_screen.draw(Game)
  ```

  ```
  def do_moves(move):
  Game.pause = True
  opponent_move = Game.opponent_move()
  if not isinstance(move, int) and not isinstance(opponent_move, int):
      ....
  ```

  to

  ```
  class SwitchMove()
  ...
  @property
  def priority():
      return (0,0)
  def do(game):
      # switch pokemon
  class PokemonMove()
  ...
  @property
  def priority():
      return (1, self.pokemon.speed)
  def do(game):
      # execute pokemon move
  ...
  def do_moves(move):
  moves = (move,Game.opponent_move())
  moves = sorted(moves,key= lambda x: x.priority)
  for move in moves:
      move.do(game)
  ```
- convert comments into functions makes the block more explicit and less likely to become out of date:

  ```
  '# Blitting the sprites
  for item in info_sprites:
      screen.blit(item[0], item[1])
  for item in secondary_info:
      Functions.text_to_screen(screen, item[0], item[1], item[2], 18)
  for item in sprites:
      screen.blit(item[0], item[1])
  ```

  ```
  def blitting_the_sprites():
      for item in info_sprites:
          screen.blit(item[0], item[1])
      for item in secondary_info:
          Functions.text_to_screen(screen, item[0], item[1], item[2], 18)
      for item in sprites:
          screen.blit(item[0], item[1])
  blitting_the_sprites()
  ```
- extract repeating structure into subobjects(more consistently structured):

  ```
  Game.Pokemon_List
  Game.current_pokemon
  Game.Pokemon_Party

  Game.Opponent_Pokemon_List
  Game.opponent.pokemon
  Game.Opponent_Party
  ```

  ```
  class Player():
      def __init__(self, pokemon_list, current_pokemon, pokemon_party):
          self.pokemon_list = pokemon_list
          self.current_pokemon = current_pokemon
          self.pokemon_party = pokemon_party

  Game.player = Player(...)
  Game.opponent = Player(...)

  Game.player.pokemon_list
  Game.player.current_pokemon
  Game.player.pokemon_party

  Game.opponent.pokemon_list
  Game.opponent.current_pokemon
  Game.opponent.pokemon_party
  ```
- remove commented out code
  temporarily it is fine but it should last only about a day and should not be checked in
  because commented out code distracts from the other code

Comment: Thanks man this helps me a lot! I have never heard of the zip() function, I will have to test it out! Also the way you coded the text_bubbles blew my mind, I had no idea that I could do that! You covered so much and I'm sure there is more to be corrected. If I could ask you a quick question: in my [link] (https://github.com/fudgenuggets1/hax_free_pokemon/blob/master/yo_buttons.py) **bold** 'yo_buttons.py' file under the do_action() method I think there should be a cleaner way to handle button actions. There is a lot of repetition there and I am not exactly sure of how to improve. Thanks again!